# D3 circular chart scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a d3 noob, so I need some help on creating a circular gauge chart. The chart should switch from red to yellow to green based on certain value.

The problem is that I want to display the text inside the chart as 0 to 100, but now it is 360 to 0. Is this possible?

Also how can I position the value at center point of my inner circle?

I change the value randomly with this code:

```
  var pi = Math.PI;
  var num = Math.random() * 360;
  var numPi = Math.floor(num - 360) * -(pi/180);
```

I've made a simple plunker to show my attempt: http://plnkr.co/edit/CREdBeHKxre2ISNqOD6N?p=preview

Comment: do you mean that the 360 will present as 100? and 0 as 0? if so, just find the function to move from [0,360] to [0,100] or even to [0,1]

Comment: Yes, exactly! But also I want to draw circle from 0 to 360. Right now 360 is the minimum value and 0 is the max value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean that the 360 will present as 100? and 0 as 0? if so, just find the function to move from [0,360] to [0,100] or even to [0,1]

and also for 360 to be the highest do this:
from:

```
var numPi = Math.floor(num - 360) * -(pi/180);
```

to:

```
var numPi = Math.floor(num) * -(pi/180);
```

Also see this:
http://www.brightpointinc.com/clients/brightpointinc.com/library/radialProgress/index.html?source=d3js

**EDIT**:

change this line:

```
  current.transition().text(Math.floor((num));// Text transition
```

to be:

```
  current.transition().text(Math.floor((num/360)*100));// Text transition
```

so now you are getting the value from 0 to 100

Comment: I want to display the text inside the chart as 0 to 100, but now it is 360 to 0.

Comment: change this to be as well as the function from [0,360] to [0,100]   current.transition().text(Math.floor(num));// Text transition